# Iframe reload on change

Tags: php

Is there any way of refreshing an iframe every time the src file changes? I am thinking about something like this:

```
while(1){
   $f1=readfile('file');
   sleep(0.2);
   $f2=readfile('file');
   if ($f1!=$f2){
       //(Reload iframe)
   }
}
```

Comment: Ajax was the answer, a lot of ajax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have an idea. You can use the sleep command to refresh an iframe if you put it inside an actual html frame on the website. So, the frame that contains the iframe reloads, leaving the rest of the page the same. This may work for you?

Comment: How do you refresh the iframe?

Comment: you don't refresh the iframe. you refresh the frame that contains the new iframe after refresh

Comment: I am a beginner in PHP, but I have experience with C++, so how do you refresh a frame?

Comment: <frameset cols="25%,50%,25%">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame src="iframe.php">
  <frame src="frame_c.htm">
</frameset> and iframe.php looks like <?php echo $iframe; sleep (10); if ($f1!=$f2) reload and echo the new iframe

Comment: this is how you refresh the php page that is your frame. parent.window.location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

no, this is not possible in php. What you can do is do polling and ask the server after every x seconds if there is any change in the file contents.

Comment: using sleep function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php sleep(10); if $f1!=$f2 then

Comment: I am familiar with the sleep function, but how do you reload the iframe?

Comment: you need to poll from the frontend. you can even send ajax requests to the backend to know if there is any change or not and if there is any change, just reload the iframe in the frontend.